# How to test redux dispatch in a class component, when a button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, testing, redux, jestjs, react-testing-library

I need to test, using the react testing library, the component when the button is clicked. I've tried a few times, but I still can't.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const { removeRegister } = this.props;

    return (
      <button data-testid="delete-btn" onClick={() => removeRegister(0)}>
        Delete
      </button>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = () => ({});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  removeExpense: (id) =>
    dispatch({
      type: "REMOVE_REGISTER",
      payload: { id },
    }),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);
```

Test:

```
  it("should trigger the actions when clicking on the buttons", () => {
    renderWithRouterAndRedux(<Table />, {
      state: mockState,
    });

    const deleteBtn = screen.getAllByTestId("delete-btn")[0];
    userEvent.click(deleteBtn );


    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ type: "REMOVE_REGISTER" });

  });
```

Comment: What happens when you run the test? How do you actually render the component? Give a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

When using React-Testing-Library you should be testing/interacting with the component API the same way users and other components do, i.e. via the props and UI. In the `Table` component when the delete button is clicked it calls a `removeRegister` callback function that was passed as a prop.

In my opinion you should test this callback is called with a given value instead of trying to mock/test external code. The store/reducers/etc should have their own unit tests.

Here's an example `Table` UI component unit test:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

// Named export for unit testing
export class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const { removeRegister } = this.props;

    return (
      <button
        data-testid="delete-btn"
        onClick={() => removeRegister(0)}
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    );
  }
}

const removeRegister = id => ({
  type: "REMOVE_REGISTER",
  payload: { id },
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  removeRegister
};

// Default export for app
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Table);
```

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { Table } from './Table'; // <-- named import for testing

it("should trigger the actions when clicking on the buttons", () => {
  const removeRegisterMock = jest.fn();

  render(<Table removeRegister={removeRegisterMock} />);

  const deleteBtn = screen.getByTestId("delete-btn");
  userEvent.click(deleteBtn);

  expect(removeRegisterMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith(0);
});
```

Comment: In this case the redux dispatch will not be untested?

Comment: @LayTexas "dispatch will not be untested" - Are you asking if the `dispatch` function will be tested by *your* tests? No, and you probably don't need to test `dispatch` since it is 3rd-party code, the Redux maintainers should have already unit tested it.